# Why hasn't my customising of reftex-cite-format been recognised?

Tags: emacs, auctex

In my `.emacs` I set up the following code to allow me to use `biblatex` cite commands when editing LaTeX files:

```
    (setq reftex-cite-format 
      '(
        (\C-m . "\\cite[]{%l}")
        (?p . "\\parencite[]{%l}")
        (?t . "\\textcite[]{%l}")))
```

But it has had no effect. It still seems to be defaulting to the set of cite commands I had set previously with `M-x customize-variable`. Why? And how do I get emacs to recognise the change? I have tried restarting emacs...

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this problem in 2018 and found a solution that might be helpful to others as well:

Auctex [introduced the variable in version 11.90](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Changes.html)

```
LaTeX-reftex-cite-format-auto-activate
```

Only if this variable is set to `nil`, the variable

```
reftex-cite-format
```

will have an effect. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31992/5701 you may have to set the variable inside `(eval-after-load 'reftex-vars`)`. This is just a guess and I notice that it might be [bad practice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html).

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'reftex-vars
  '(progn
     (setq reftex-cite-format
           '((\C-m . "\\cite[]{%l}")
             (?p . "\\parencite[]{%l}")
             (?t . "\\textcite[]{%l}")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but at the end of my .emacs file is a `custom-set-variables` block which is written to when I use `M-x customize-variable`. Maybe yours is the same, and your changes to `reftex-cite-format` are being overwritten by this?

Comment: Yeah I thought of that. I didn't see anything setting `reftex-cite-format` in the `custom-set-variables` block and putting the above code at the very end of my `.emacs` doesn't make a difference.